# android : How can I view the same button in different places

Tags: android

I have a button in my application labeled `mailHandler`. on click, the button changes color and launches a looping thread. if the thread is already alive, clicking on the button closes the loop, and the button's color changes to what it was before clicking it.

What I want to do is to be able to use this button in two different fragments; say I clicked the button in `layout1`, I want to see both the buttons in `layout1` and in `layout2` change their colors. Or if I clicked the button in `layout1`, I want clicking it in `layout2` to close the looping thread the button in `layout1` started, vice versa.

what can I do?

Comment: layout1 knows nothing about layout2 and furthermore only one of these layouts will be active and visible, so i don't really understand what you mean. pass this data over to layout 2 when you create it, use the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you look into using [ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

When you put your looping logic into a shared `ViewModel`, you can observe its state in both fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can have button in main activity - Activity that is holding these fragments rather than defining different buttons in both of the fragments. If your requirement is to add different buttons on each fragment then you can transfer the data from one fragment to another via interface/callback implementation.